# define integral over non-measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let's consider a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$,and then we define a new measure, choose algebra $\mathcal{M}_0\subset\mathcal{M}$,and $\mu_0=\mu|_{\mathcal{M}_0}$, then for nonnegative $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mu_0$, is this integral $\int_Xfd\mu_0$ well defined?

(My thought): If we choose $X\notin \mathcal{M}_0$, then this integral is not well-defined, since $\mu_0$ only defined on $\mathcal{M}_0$.

---

### Updates

1. $\mathcal{M}_0$ can be a sigma-algebra without including $X$,For example,$X=[0,2]$,if $\mathcal{M}=2^{[0,2]}$,then $X\notin 2^{[0,1]}\subset 2^{[0,2]}$.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking here: If you take $M_0\subset M$, then $M_0$ consists only of measurable sets - and certainly, if $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mu_0$, you can integrate it with respect to $\mu_0$. And, $X$ must be in $M_0$ by the definition of a sigma algebra. This question contains some serious contradictions.

Comment: @milo brandt , why $X$ must be in $M_0$?

Comment: It's part of the definition of a sigma algebra (or, at least we get "closed under complements and contains the empty set" which implies $X=\emptyset^C$ is in it)

Comment: Let's consider such example: let $X=[0,2]$,then $\mathcal{M}=2^{[0,2]}$,then let $\mathcal{M}_0=2^{[0,1]}$,we have $\mathcal{M}_0\subset \mathcal{M}$,but $X\notin \mathcal{M}_0$

Comment: Yes, but $M_0$ wouldn't be a sigma algebra on $X$ anymore. It would be a sigma algebra on a subset of $X$.

Comment: Yes, so in this case , we have a new measure space $(X_0,\mathcal{M}_0,\mu_0)$, then the integral $\int_Xfd\mu_0$ is not defined, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it is not defined then. (But it's also not particularly correct to say that $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mu_0$ since we would only even ask about measurability for a function with domain $X_0$)

Comment: 1. If $\mathcal{M}_0$ is an algebra (or a sigma algebra), by definition $X \in \mathcal{M}_0$.  2. $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{M}_0$, not $\mu_0$. 3. If $f$ is a non-negative measurable function with respect to $\mathcal{M}_0$, then the integral $\int_Xfd\mu_0$ is well defined.

Comment: @Ramiro, 1. $\mathcal{M}_0$ is sigma algebra,but no granting that $X\in\mathcal{M}_0$.   3. We don't need $f$ be nonnegative.

Comment: 1. Please, check the definition of sigma-algebra.  If you dont want to grant that$X \in \mathcal{M}_0$, then you must say $\mathcal{M}_0$ is a sigma-ring.  Another, option is to say $\mathcal{M}_0$ is a sigma-algebra on $X_0$, where $X_0$ is a subset of $X$. In this case $X_0 \in \mathcal{M}_0$, but it would make no sense to write $\int_X f d\mu_0$. You should write $\int_{X_0} f d\mu_0$.

3. If $f$ is a measurable function, but it is not non-negative then $\int f$ may be undefined, since we may have $\int f^+=\int f^-=+\infty$.

Comment: It is possible to define integrals on sigma-rings. See Halmos, Measure Theory.

Comment: You wrote: "1. $\mathcal{M}_0$ can be a sigma-algebra without including $X$,For example,$X=[0,2]$,if $\mathcal{M}=2^{[0,2]}$,then $X\notin 2^{[0,1]}\subset 2^{[0,2]}$".  IT IS NOT CORRECT.  $2^{[0,1]}$ is not a sigma-algebra on $[0,2]$, it is just a sigma-ring on $[0,2]$.  Of course, you may say $2^{[0,1]}$ is a sigma-algebra on $[0,1]$, but then you have changed the space from $[0,2]$ to $[0,1]$.  Please check the definitions of sigma-algebra and sigma-ring.

Answer (score 0):

You define the measurable sets in your space specifically to avoid "nasty" sets. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, which is usually a good place to test ideas, one cannot define a measure so that

1) Every set is measurable

2) The measure preserves the length of an interval

3) The measure is translation invariant

4) The measure is countably additivity

So in general, it would not make sense to try and force our measure to work on all subsets of our measure space, as these last properties are essential for the idea's of integration to work as we want. Therefore we must live with the fact that there are sets which we cannot measure in a given measure space.

You can take some solace in the fact that pretty much any set in $\mathbb{R}$ which is not measurable is concocted using the axiom of choice.

Comment: I care the integral.

Comment: But if the set is not measurable, you cannot take the integral. If you attempt to define the integral you would need to find a way to measure the set, which means using a different measure which is not equivalent to the original on the sets which are measurable with respect to both measures.